# Distributed Cache Hadoop and Scalability

Tags: java, hadoop

I have a list of files that I want to add using distributed cache facility. Different files are needed for different reduce tasks. For example, file A is needed by reduce 1, while file B is needed by reduce 2, and so on. 
In Job Conf, both the files are added using DistributedCache.addCacheFile() method. 
In the reduce class configure method, I use DistributedCache.getCacheFiles() to get the files.
Is it possible that I can have only File A in memory of reduce 1 and only file B in memory of reduce 2. Or the both the files get added to the memory, before the reduce task starts.

If I understand this, I can use distributed cache for my program. My concern is about scalability. The files are big. So the reduce task cannot have both the files in memory. But can hold one of the files.

Pls help!!!

Thanks

Comment: Distributed cache is not in memory, it is just a confusing name of copying files along with your jar to every host where computation runs.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. So, we can add a file is as large as the disk space of the node can hold?

Comment: When the reducer processes the file, is it necessary to hold the entire file in memory?

Comment: Depends on how the files are processed in the mapper/reducer. Hadoop framework provides [hooks](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.20.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html) to get the list of files in the cache, then the content of the files can be read and `kept/or not` in memory as per the requirements. Hadoop framework copies all the cache files to the HDD on the TastTracker and there is a limit of 10GB based on the `local.cache.size`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method for returning the cache files, returns an array of all the names of the files you cached in the order you added them. So it is possible to tell reducer 1 to get the array[0] file and reduce 2 to get the array[1] file. This cache is also recommended not to have very large files in it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! So, irrespective of the number of files added in distributed cache, the reducer can choose the one it wants. Am I correct? And since it is copying it to the reduce node, it is copying it to the disk, so the file can be as large as the disk space of the node, right?

Comment: The Mapper/Reducer can get the list of files in the cache using DistributedCache and it can process the required file. But, the catch is Hadoop framework will copy all the files to the TaskTracker node irrespective of the file is used or not by the Mapper/Reducer.

Comment: Thanks! That really cleared my doubt. I have one more question. Since it is copying the files to every node, the file that is copied is transferred via the network(I suppose), so will it not affect the network performance, if the file is big or if there are lot of nodes?